# Конвертировать объект даты в ISO8601 Duration (D1M1Y2)

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Искал библиотеки или модули для конвертирования объекта даты в DURATION ISO-8601 с таким форматом
D1 - один день
M1 - один месяц
Y1 - один год

Есть ли такие библиотеки или модули ? К сожалению сам не нашел
Нужно чтобы пользователь выбрал дату например в календаре, а потом выбранную дату конвертировать в формат который написал выше D1M1Y1

Comment: `moment.duration().toISOString();` https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/